# NSNotificationCenter dispatch table

Tags: ios, notifications, notificationcenter

NSNotificationCenter is used to dispatch the objects across observers. I would like to know how notification center's dispatch table looks.

When we add an observer it adds to notification center's dispatch table. And notification queue will push the notification object to notification center to dispatch.

Now what action is taking place when notification queue push a new notification object to notification center. I'm not finding a necessary tutorial in google. Please provide a good link which talks about action of dispatch table.

Thanks,

Comment: What i should do since it's a off question for this blog? should i remove the question from here?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check out the ["Notification Queue Basics" section of the "Notification Queues" chapter of the "Notification Programming Topics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000217-SW1). It contains a good explanation of the process of posting notifications.

Comment: thanks for the replay. I was looking for pictorial representation. But i got know few information from given link.